# How can i study this function?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I'm currently trying to study this function.

$$y=x-4 \arctan |x-3|$$

I tried my best to find its roots and to study its sign, but I simply cannot solve the equation $x-4\arctan|x-3|=0$. Can anyone give me a hand?

I tried by dividing the function into two separate functions: y=x and $y=4\arctan|x-3|$ Then I put this two new functions on paper to find the point where they intersect that is around $x=2.33$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! What methods did you try so far?

Comment: Start with pen and paper, and sketch it.

Comment: I tried by dividing the function into two separate functions:

y=x and y=4arctan|x-3|
Then I put this two new functions on paper to find the point where they intersect that is  around x=2.33

Answer (score 1):

In terms of graphical visualization, using desmos, we know the solution is around $2.33$,

[image]

Here is a numerical approach.

\begin{align}f(x)&=x-4\arctan|(x-3)|   \\&= \begin{cases}x - 4\arctan(3-x), & x< 3\\ 3, &x=3\\ x - 4\arctan(x-3), & x> 3\end{cases}\end{align}

\begin{align}f'(x)= \begin{cases}1 + \frac{4}{1+(3-x)^2}, & x< 3\\ 1 - \frac{4}{1+(x-3)^2}, & x> 3\end{cases}\end{align}

Now we can use a numerical scheme such as Newton-Raphson method:

```
import numpy as np


# Define the function and its derivative
def f(x):
    return x - 4 * np.arctan(np.abs(x - 3))


def f_prime(x):
    if x<3:
        return 1 + 4/(1+(x-3)**2)
    else:
        return 1 - 4/(1+(x-3)**2)


# Set an initial guess
x_guess = 0.0

# Set a tolerance for the solution
tolerance = 1e-8

# Perform the iterations
for _ in range(100):  # You can adjust the number of iterations as needed
    x_new = x_guess - f(x_guess) / f_prime(x_guess)
    print(x_new)

    # Check for convergence
    if abs(x_new - x_guess) < tolerance:
        break

    x_guess = x_new

# Print the result
print("Approximate solution:", x_new)
```

and the solution is around  $2.3382801746124597$

Perhaps you can proceed to study the turning points using the derivative? It should just involve solving quadratic equations.

Comment: +1 : Very thorough, good graphics.